# CoreMediaIO doesn't present the virtual camera

Tags: macos

I'm trying to run [CoreMediaIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html) example. I did the next actions:

1. Downloaded the source.
2. Performed in Terminal:

   ```
   xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Sample-Debug.tar.gz
   ```
3. Installed data from Prebuilts :

   ```
   sudo darwinup install {path to CoreMediaIO folder}/Prebuilts/Sample-Debug.tar.gz
   ```
4. Fixed errors of the project and compiled. I got the results `Sample.plugin`, `com.apple.cmio.DPA.Sample.plist` and `IOVideoSample.kext`
5. I moved the data by the result paths.
6. Updated the kext's permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 755 IOVideoSample.kext
   sudo chown -R root:wheel IOVideoSample.kext
   ```
7. [Disabled KEXT's signing enforcement](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269777)
8. Rebooted the system.

But I can't access to DAL-plugin with Skype Version 7.46 (56758). Please could you help me?
I have MacOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually loading the kext using something like

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/IOVideoSample.kext
```

You might not have set the auto start by default.